# Buttons randomly shrink

Tags: android, flutter

I'm having an issue where buttons on my welcome screen are randomly not taking up all the horizontal space they have available.

[Incorrect small buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZ3JX.png)

[Normally how the buttons display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXuc7.png)

Small snippet of the button code itself:

```
Column(
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 1, 45, 0),
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () => controller.login(context),
        child: const Text(Constants.logIn),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 20),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 0, 45, 0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text(Constants.signUp),
        onPressed: () => controller.openPanel(
          SlidingPanelState.signup,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

This only happens on android and when I install the app from the store, not when I install the apk directly from a local build.

It feels similar to when you needed to use jquery Document.ready() to let things render to be able to grab the correct size of an element (or container). I can't seem to find anything in flutter about this issue though so I'm at a loss at why this could be happening.

Thanks for any information!

Comment: Add to your column `crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`

Comment: Ya but the issue is sometimes it looks correct, but sometimes it looks like those small buttons. On the same device it randomly happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add crossAxisAlignment property to your column and set it to CrossAxisAlignment.stretch

```
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment:CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
  children: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 1, 45, 0),
      child: OutlinedButton(
        onPressed: () => controller.login(context),
        child: const Text(Constants.logIn),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(height: 20),
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(45, 0, 45, 0),
      child: ElevatedButton(
        child: const Text(Constants.signUp),
        onPressed: () => controller.openPanel(
          SlidingPanelState.signup,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```